# Query mongodb from command line and send the result as HTTP request in crontab

Tags: bash, mongodb, monitoring, cron

I want to incorporate a simple monitoring into my application so I need to send an HTTP request that contains the number of documents in the mongodb collection from the crontab.

The requests are described on the page http://countersrv.com/ as follows:

```
curl http://countersrv.com/ID -d value=1
```

I need to query the mongodb from the command line and get the number of documents in the collection. It should be something like `db.my_docs.count()`.

I want to send this number every hour so need to add something like this into crontab:

```
0 * * * * curl http://countersrv.com/ID -d value=...query mongo here...?
```

Answer (score 7):

I would avoid using commands directly on crontab, you probably have a directory /etc/cron.hourly and crontab already have calls to run all the scripts in the specific folders, in determined intervals, hourly, daily for example

Then, inside /etc/cron.hourly you can create a monitor.sh. You can set the execution privilege of this script with

```
chmod +x /etc/cron.hourly/monitor.sh
```

Them, you make a js code to retrieve the data, for example, mongoscript.js:

```
use yourdb
db.my_docs.count()
```

And you final monitor.sh will probably be something like

```
#!/bin/bash
mongo mongoscript.js > output.js
curl http://countersrv.com/ID -d value=@output.js
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please let me know how exactly pipe should set the value of the POST parameter for CURL? Does curl parse the -d parameter and if detects the incomplete data then read it from stdin?

Comment: You can use a .js file to setup a mongo script then run, mongo script.js  , about the pipe I'm pretty sure that is missing something, but I'm without Linux to tell you at moment

Comment: For pipe it is `-d @-` I think.

Comment: Thank for confirming @NeilLunn I googled some seconds before and seems correct

Answer (score 7):

Not meaning to detract from the timely answer given by Victor, but the "one liner" form of this would be:

```
 mongo --quiet --eval 'var db = db.getSiblingDB("database"); print( "value=" + db.collection.count() );' | curl -X POST http://countersrv.com/[edit endpoint] -d @-
```

The `--quiet` suppresses the startup message on the shell and `--eval` alows the commands to pass through on the command line.

To select the database you use `.getSiblingDB()` as the method helper for the interactive shell `use database` with the "database" name you want. After this either just the "collection" name or `.getCollection()` method can be used along with the basic function.

Simply `print()` the "key/value" pair required and pipe to `curl` at the "edit endpoint" for countersrv, which is the default viewing page. The `@-` construct takes stdin.

Comment: @VictorH.Panisa You were first really. I just added this for posterity.Sorry, I always talk like that. "In case someone actually wanted the one-liner". I up-voted you before anyway.

Comment: Don't need to sorry ^^ thanks for complementing the answer. Also I up-voted you too =]